# how to remove SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, json

I using form wizard type,in that form i have 3 steps .

1. Basic data
2. moreinformation
3. confirmation

I filled 1st step means and click the submit(next) button, I got value from here **register-newuser.php** from that page I wrote if condition like this

```
if (!empty($birthday && $department)) {do something}
```

Which was giving me

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**
```

So I changed the if condition to

```
if (!empty($birthday)) { do something}
```

Which works, but I also want to check `$birthday` and `$department`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#user-submit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData();
    var formData = new FormData($('#newUserForm')[0]);
    formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
     
    $.ajax({
      url: 'php/register-newuser.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (data) {
        var res=jQuery.parseJSON(data);// convert the json
        console.log(res);
      },
    });
  });
});


// register-newuser.php

<?php
/*Basic Date*/
$fstname=$_POST['fname'];
$filename  = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$new_name= md5($filename.time()).'.'.$extension;

$original_date = $_POST['birthday'];
$birthday = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($original_date));

$department = $_POST['department'];

 
if (!empty($Work_Shifts AND $zipcode)) {
  $newuser = array ("firstname" =>$fstname,"filename" =>$new_name,"birthday" =>$birthday,"department" =>$department,"status" => "success");
  echo json_encode($newuser);
} else {
  $newuser = array("status" => "error");
  echo json_encode($newuser);
} 
?>
```

```html
<section class="panel form-wizard" id="w2">
   <div class="tabs">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justify wizard-steps">
  <li class="active">
     <a href="#w2-account" data-toggle="tab" class="text-center">
     <span class="badge hidden-xs">1</span>
     Basic Data
     </a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="#w2-profile" data-toggle="tab" class="text-center">
     <span class="badge hidden-xs">2</span>
     More Information
     </a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="#w2-confirm" data-toggle="tab" class="text-center">
     <span class="badge hidden-xs">3</span>
     Confirm
     </a>
  </li>
   </ul>
   <form class="form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate" method="POST" id="newUserForm">
  <div class="tab-content" style="margin:15px">
     <div id="w2-account" class="tab-pane active">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-md-3 control-label">First Name<span class="star_mark">&nbsp;*</span></label>
           <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" value="" aria-required="true" required="" data-msg-required="Please enter your firstname" placeholder="Enter your firstname">
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Photo Upload<span class="star_mark">&nbsp;*</span></label>
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                 <div class="input-append">
                    <div class="uneditable-input">
                       <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                    <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
                    <span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
                    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" value="" aria-required="true" required="" data-msg-required="Please select your file">
                    </span>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="w2-profile" class="tab-pane">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Birth Day <span class="star_mark">&nbsp;*</span></label>
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                 <span class="input-group-addon">
                 <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                 </span>
                 <input type="text" data-plugin-datepicker="" class="form-control" id="birthday" name="birthday" value="" aria-required="true" required="" data-msg-required="Please select your birth day" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputDefault">Department <span class="star_mark">&nbsp;*</span></label>
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Department" id="department" name="department" value="" aria-required="true" required="" data-msg-required="Please enter your department">
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="w2-confirm" class="tab-pane">
        <div class="alert alert-success">
           <strong>Success!</strong> Form has been successfully submitted.
        </div>
     </div>
   </form>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-footer">
  <ul class="pager">
     <li class="previous disabled">
        <a><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Previous</a>
     </li>
     <!-- <li class="finish hidden pull-right">
        <a>Finish</a>
        </li> -->
     <li class="next" id="user-submit">
        <a>Next <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
     </li>
  </ul>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Getting error like this     <br/>
<b>Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected '&amp;&amp;' (T_BOOLEAN_AND), expecting ')' in <b>/home
/srisanka/public_html/cupid/TV/php/register-newuser.php</b> on line <b>41</b><br/>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way your AJAX call expects data to be sent back. You need to do two things.

First, add the header to PHP to tell the client you are sending JSON back:

```
// This should be one of the first lines in the PHP file
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Second, use `$.ajax`'s `dataType` property to read the JSON back like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'php/register-newuser.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  dataType: 'json', // This tells jQuery that it is getting JSON back - it will parse it for you
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function (data) {
    // data will be parsed by jQuery into an object or array based on the JSON
    console.log(data);
  },
});
```

Comment: Hai Matthew Herbst i did your line code but still now getting same error

Comment: @KaniR you added the header line to your PHP, added the `dataType` to the ajax call, and removed the `var res=jQuery.parseJSON(data);` ?

Comment: Getting error like this <br/>
<b>Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected '&amp;&amp;' (T_BOOLEAN_AND), expecting ')' in <b>/home
/srisanka/public_html/cupid/TV/php/register-newuser.php</b> on line <b>41</b><br/>

Comment: Do you have a single file with your PHP and HTML on it?

Comment: No, html file is diffrent in that html file i wrote js and PHP file different i create one folder called PHP and inside PHP folder i wrote php code name is register-newuser.php'

Comment: Well, it sounds like you just have a syntax error in your PHP then on line 41. It was likely being masked by your other error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add the property `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax call and remove the method `jQuery.parseJson(data)` in your success callback.

Example:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'php/register-newuser.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hai user2069766 i getting like this error<br/>
<b>Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected '&amp;&amp;' (T_BOOLEAN_AND), expecting ')' in <b>/home
/srisanka/public_html/cupid/TV/php/register-newuser.php</b> on line <b>41</b><br/>